# JSON data fetching through Yahoo! Placefinder

Tags: javascript, json, api, yahoo

I am trying to retrieve information from the Placefinder API.  My code takes information from a text box and sends it to yahoo on a button click.

```
            function codeAddress(){
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            var RequestUrl = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q="+address+"&flags=J&callback=ws_results&output=json";
            JSONObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
            JSONObject.open( "GET", RequestUrl, false );
            JSONObject.send( null );
            return JSONObject;
            document.getElementByID("jlatitude").innerHTML=JSONObject.latitude;
            alert(document.write("jlatitude"));
        }
```

Firebug tells me that the data is returned, yet I cannot display what I want in a troubleshooting popup.  The placefinder returns this when I request the geocoding for Maryland.

```
{"ResultSet":{"version":"1.0","Error":0,"ErrorMessage":"No error","Locale":"us_US","Quality":10,"Found":2,"Results":[{"quality":49,"latitude":"39.466626","longitude":"-93.709069","offsetlat":"39.466626","offsetlon":"-93.709069","radius":700,"name":"","line1":"","line2":"Roads, MO","line3":"","line4":"United States","house":"","street":"","xstreet":"","unittype":"","unit":"","postal":"","neighborhood":"Roads","city":"Norborne","county":"Carroll County","state":"Missouri","country":"United States","countrycode":"US","statecode":"MO","countycode":"","uzip":"64668","hash":"","woeid":2482523,"woetype":7},{"quality":49,"latitude":"39.080130","longitude":"-82.537394","offsetlat":"39.080130","offsetlon":"-82.537394","radius":700,"name":"","line1":"","line2":"Roads, OH","line3":"","line4":"United States","house":"","street":"","xstreet":"","unittype":"","unit":"","postal":"","neighborhood":"Roads","city":"Wellston","county":"Jackson County","state":"Ohio","country":"United States","countrycode":"US","statecode":"OH","countycode":"","uzip":"45692","hash":"","woeid":2482522,"woetype":7}]}}
```

My alert box does not appear, but the data is stored.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.getJSON(RequestUrl,{},function(result){
  ...
});
```

This properly retrieves a JSON object from the Yahoo! Placefinder

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got a simple problem in your JavaScript code example - after receiving the data from YQL, you have `return JSONObject;` which means the following lines will never be executed.

To troubleshoot and confirm, you could write to the console log upon return, something like:

```
function codeAddress(){
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    var RequestUrl = "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q="+address+"&flags=J&callback=ws_results&output=json";
    JSONObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    JSONObject.open( "GET", RequestUrl, false );
    JSONObject.send( null );
    console.log( JSONObject.responseText );
}
```